# XHR2 Progress Fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following example which uses the progress events in XHR2 to display a progress bar to the user when performing an AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {

        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt){

            if (evt.lengthComputable) {

                var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;

                if(percentComplete >= 100){
                    $('#loading-bar').find('.bar').css({'width': percentComplete + '%'});
                    $('#loading-bar')
                    .find('.bar')
                    .on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function() {
                        $('#loading-bar').fadeOut(function(){
                            $('#loading-bar').find('.bar').css({'width': ''});
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#loading-bar').find('.bar').css({'width': percentComplete + '%'});
                }
            }                               

        }, false);

        return xhr;

    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Test.html',
    success: function (response) {


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


    }
});
```

However for browsers that don't support XHR2, the bar won't animate nor will the loading-bar element be faded out from the DOM.

How can I implement a fallback? As I don't want to just fade the loading bar out on success as that will then conflict with the progress events for browsers that DO support it.

**Or even better is it possible to get the progress by alternate means?**

Comment: Some browsers that do not implement the progress api will still allow you to access the `.response.length` and the `content-length` header after the headers are received. For uploading, you're out of luck afaik.

Comment: Why not check in your succes function if xhr2 is supported and if its not than only fade out.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think I care about the upload progress... just the download one which I'm showing in my question. Do you have some examples for how I can use the alternate APIs. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding the situation, but would `.readyState` be of any help? Maybe you could simplify your loading bar for XHR by using `.readyState`.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Please feel free to show an example. Thanks.

Comment: Use http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html. I used this and it is a wonderful solution for rich internet applications. It has got this capability of falling back to use iFrame for legacy browsers. If you are looking for code for iFrame based upload, ping and I can help.

Comment: @VijaySarin This isn't a question on how to send files using AJAX (I know about the Ifame hack for HTML4 browsers due to them not supporting FormData).

Answer (score 1):

If it's download progress, we can do it when `xhr.readyState >= 3`. Just read the `xhr.responseText.length`, and then divide it by `parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'))` (assuming the server provides this header and it's same origin or with correct CORS header).

If it's upload progress, I don't know any method to polyfill it purely within the client-side. We can create an id for every upload session, and use another `xhr` to pull the upload receiving progress from the server. However that requires complicated implementation on the server-side. There are many such implementations in common languages, for example for PHP or .NET. You can look into them and implement your own.

Comment: Only interested in the download progress. Could you show a simple example of how I can update the width of the progress bar based on your solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron: `xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { if (xhr.readyState >= 3) { var progress = xhr.responseText.length / parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length')); } };`

Comment: You should put that in your answer and then I'll give it a test.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.onreadystatechange()` with `.readyState`:

```
getter.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (loading) { //If the loading element has been loaded...
        if (this.status === 200) { //If this.status is already 200...
            loading.style.width = this.readyState*25+"%"; //This sets the width of loading according to this.readyState
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                //We hide loadingBar and do stuff when we're done.
                loadingBar.style.display = "none";
               [do stuff]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If you're accepting `100 Continue` statuses, you might also want to account for that into your loading bar. The way this is now, it's at a standstill for a while, but then zooms to 100% when it gets to the status `200 OK` and the `readyState` property goes from `2` to `4`.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NobleMushtak/QRuU6/